# RegEx match making with any character length

Tags: php, regex, validation

Hi so I need to write a program where it validates input.

The specifications are " letters, spaces, colon, semi-colon, dash, comma, apostrophe and numeric character (0-9) only - cannot be blank"

I know how to do this when I have an explicit number of characters to use, but in this case it can be any amount of characters, 1-50 and I do not know what to do for regular expression notation in this case of any number of characters. How can I start this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the `+` character if you're trying to match any number of something (but at least one). Here's is an example:

```
^[A-Za-z :;\-,'\d]+$
```

Answer (score 2):

When you say that the input line cannot be blank I imagine that, while you want to allow spaces, the line itself cannot be spaces only.

Based on that perception I suggest this regex. The negative lookahead, in parentheses, make sure that the line is not all spaces.

```
^(?!\s+$)[-A-Za-z0-9:;'\s]{1,50}$
```

Answer (score 1):

To match the whole string:

`^[A-Za-z0-9 :;,'-]{1,50}$`

To match it as part of a string:

`[A-Za-z0-9 :;,'-]{1,50}`

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to represent multiplicities in regular expressions:

`k?` means there is either 0 or 1 `k` possible, i.e.   or `k`

`k*`means there are 0 or more `k`s possible, e.g.  , `k`, `kk`, ...

`k+` means there are 1 or more `k`s possible, e.g. `k`, `kk`, ...

`k{5}` means there are exactly 5 `k`s, i.e `kkkkk`

`k{3,}` means there are *at least* 3 `k`s, e.g. `kkk`, `kkkk`, ...

`k{2,4}` means there are either 2, 3 or 4 `k`s.

For further reading please see the corresponding page of the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php).

Comment: Nice explanation, only `k{,5}` missing there.

Comment: Due to the linked page `k{,5}`is not a quantifier `{,6} is not a quantifier, but a literal string of four characters.`

Comment: Oh, yeah! Reminded me of something I had forgotten: it's always written as `k{0,max}`.